# How to keep VLC playing while screen is locked

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, kubuntu

VLC pauses a video that's looping after screen is locked on Kubuntu.
How to keep it playing, while keeping the screen lock?
Pause media players is disabled in advanced energy settings Kubuntu.

Comment: Check "man vlc" for no pause option